# Insert Into Script Not Working Properly For Users

Tags: php

I am currently working on developing a website, and for whatever reason, my script to create users has decided that it does not want to add users.
I'm fairly new to PHP coding, so I'm not quite good at troubleshooting it yet.

This first bit of code is the script that I believe to be causing the issue, however again, I am not sure, so I will also provide the db.php code

```
<?php
include('classes/db.php');

if (isset($_POST['createaccount'])) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];


        db::query('INSERT INTO users VALUES (null,:username, :password, :email', array(':username'=>$username, ':password'=>$password, ':email'=>$email));
        echo "Success";

 }
?>
```

This second bit of code is what is being included.

```
<?php 
 class DB{

    public static function connect() {
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "username";
        $password = "pass";
        $database = "database";

        try {
            $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
            // set the PDO error mode to exception
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            echo "Connected successfully"; 
            } catch(PDOException $e) {    
            echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
            }
         if (isset($_POST['createaccount'])) {
                $username = $_POST['username'];
                $password = $_POST['password'];
                $email = $_POST['email'];
         return $pdo;
     }
    }
     public static function query($query, $params) {
        $statement = self::connect()->prepare($query);
        $statement->execute();
        $data = $statement->fetchAll();
        return $data;

     }
 }
?>
```

Most of the code in use here has been thrown together using tutorials, so that reason in probably what is causing the error here.

Comment: avoid using login credentials in questions

Comment: you should have a form that refers to a php page in its action.
e.g.
page.php: <form action='page2.php' method='post'><input type='text' name='username'/><input type='email' name='email'/><input type='password' name='password'/></form>
page2.php: has your db.php code

Comment: You forgot to close bracket in insert query. change your query to `'INSERT INTO users VALUES (null,:username, :password, :email)'`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create a new file e.g.form.php

```
<form action='db.php' method='post'>
<input type='text' name='username'/>
<input type='email' name='email'/>
<input type='password' name='password'/>
<input type='submit' name='createaccount' value='createaccount'/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the file "classes/db.php" included?If not try changing the path to absolute path and not the relative one,say your file "db.php" is present in C:/Users/A/Desktop then your include statement should be

include('C:/Users/A/Desktop/db.php');